# How to retrieve row names from each list levels after applying max.col

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following list :

```
L1=list(y1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("PURPLE", "YELLOW"), c("1", "2", "3")), .Names = c("", 
"")), class = "table"), y2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
5L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("LARGE", "SMALL"
), c("1", "2", "3")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table"), 
    y3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("DIP", "STRETCH"), c("1", "2", "3")), .Names = c("", 
    "")), class = "table"), y4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("ADULT", 
    "CHILD"), c("1", "2", "3")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table"), 
    y5 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("FALSE", "TRUE"), c("1", "2", "3")), .Names = c("", 
    "")), class = "table"))
#output
> L1
$y1
        
         1 2 3
  PURPLE 2 5 3
  YELLOW 2 3 4

$y2
       
        1 2 3
  LARGE 3 5 2
  SMALL 1 3 5

$y3
         
          1 2 3
  DIP     2 3 3
  STRETCH 2 5 4

$y4
       
        1 2 3
  ADULT 3 4 4
  CHILD 1 4 3

$y5
       
        1 2 3
  FALSE 3 5 4
  TRUE  1 3 3
```

For each variable $y , I tried to get **the modalities** that are the most frequent ( for each column). For each column , i tried to retrieve the row with the maximum frequency as following :

```
lapply(res, function(x) max.col(t(x)))
$y1
[1] 2 1 2

$y2
[1] 1 1 2

$y3
[1] 1 2 2

$y4
[1] 1 1 1

$y5
[1] 1 1 1
```

Now , i need to get the associated modalities , for example :

```
    $y1
    [1] YELLOW PURPLE YELLOW
    $y2
    [1] LARGE LARGE SMALL
...
```

I tried without success : `lapply(res, function(x) rownames(max.col(t(x))))`

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *subset* `rownames(x)` with the index, and not call it with the index, to get the names.

```
lapply(L1, function(x) rownames(x)[max.col(t(x))])
#$y1
#[1] "PURPLE" "PURPLE" "YELLOW"
#
#$y2
#[1] "LARGE" "LARGE" "SMALL"
#
#$y3
#[1] "DIP"     "STRETCH" "STRETCH"
#
#$y4
#[1] "ADULT" "ADULT" "ADULT"
#
#$y5
#[1] "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE"
```